# Asp .Net MVC with Windows Authtication and SQL Server Role Based Provider

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows-authentication, roleprovider

Did anybody make MVC + Windows Auth + SQL Server role based provider work on IIS 7.0?
Any pointers will be helpful.

Comment: I got something which can solve my problem http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc949054.aspx, let me know if anybody knows any better options.

Comment: It might hepl us help you if you were more specific. Is there any error message/exception you're getting? Do you have any clue as to which part of the chain isn't working?

Answer (score 1):

MVC 3 tooling update released today has a Windows Auth Template that might be of some help.